# Issues displaying average data from ADC

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having an issue with my code. I'm trying to read voltage measurements from my ADC and get the average of every 100 readings then display the average on my default screen. The process is supposed to repeat and the label should be updating every 0.5 seconds. However, my label doesn't even show on the screen.

These are some snippets of my code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
GAIN = 1

LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana', 18)
NORM_FONT = ('Verdana', 14)
SMALL_FONT = ('Verdana' , 11)
MENU_FONT= ('Arial', 12, "bold")



def update_label(label):

    def getvoltage():

        readings = [0]*100
        maxsample = 100
        counter = 0

        while (counter < maxsample):

            reading = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
            readings.append(reading)
            counter += 1

        avg = sum(readings)/100
        voltage = (avg * 0.1259)/100
        readings.clear()

        label.config(text=str('Voltage: {0:.2f}'.format(voltage)))
    label.after(500, getvoltage)



class Controller(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Controller")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)    
        self.show_frame(DefaultScreen)

class DefaultScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.configure(bg="white")

        f = Figure(figsize = (10,3), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16])

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Contact Page",
                            command=lambda:controller.show_frame(ContactPage))
        button1.pack(anchor="se", pady=10, padx=10)
        ventilatorstatus="Ventilator Status: Closed"
        ventstatus= tk.Label(self, text=ventilatorstatus, font=LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        ventstatus.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, anchor="center")
        voltage_label = tk.Label(self, font=LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        voltage_label.place(relx=0.5, rely= 0.22, anchor="center")
        update_label(voltage_label)

        canvas= FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(anchor="s", fill=tk.X, expand=True, pady=20)



app = Controller()
app.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
app.mainloop()
```

It would be great if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong..
Thank you :)

Comment: Assuming your indentation as posted here matches your actual code, `update_label()` does absolutely nothing - it contains a definition of a nested function, but there's no code to run.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have edited it and now it shows the measurement. However, it is not updating every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: The `label.after()` needs to be inside `getvoltage()` in order to continuously schedule the next update.  You then need a single call to `getvoltage()` to start the process.

Comment: Oh, that seems to have solved the problem. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might find the answer useful:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
GAIN = 1

LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana', 18)
NORM_FONT = ('Verdana', 14)
SMALL_FONT = ('Verdana' , 11)
MENU_FONT= ('Arial', 12, "bold")



def update_label(label):

    def getvoltage():

        readings = [0]*100
        maxsample = 100
        counter = 0

        while (counter < maxsample):

            reading = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
            readings.append(reading)
            counter += 1

        avg = sum(readings)/100
        voltage = (avg * 0.1259)/100
        readings.clear()

        label.config(text=str('Voltage: {0:.2f}'.format(voltage)))
        label.after(500, getvoltage)
    getvoltage()



class Controller(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Controller")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)    
        self.show_frame(DefaultScreen)

class DefaultScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.configure(bg="white")

        f = Figure(figsize = (10,3), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16])

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Contact Page",
                            command=lambda:controller.show_frame(ContactPage))
        button1.pack(anchor="se", pady=10, padx=10)
        ventilatorstatus="Ventilator Status: Closed"
        ventstatus= tk.Label(self, text=ventilatorstatus, font=LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        ventstatus.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, anchor="center")
        voltage_label = tk.Label(self, font=LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        voltage_label.place(relx=0.5, rely= 0.22, anchor="center")
        update_label(voltage_label)

        canvas= FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(anchor="s", fill=tk.X, expand=True, pady=20)



app = Controller()
app.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
app.mainloop()
```